# Recycler View Adding Previous Content On New Contents

Tags: android

Thanks for the help as always. I am making a firebase chat app and i ran into this bug and i can figure out what is happening.

Usually if i clear the database and start fresh, the error doesnt occur but
Whenever i send a message, an older received message is included in the new one in the recyclerview. i am lost and frustrated. I have searched through stackoverflow for solution to no positive result. Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image: screenshot]

```
private void loadMessages() {

    chatMessagesRef = db.getReference("ChatMessages").child(Common.currentUser.getMatric()).child(user_id);
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, ChatMessageViewHolder>(
            Message.class,
            R.layout.single_message_item,
            ChatMessageViewHolder.class,
            chatMessagesRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ChatMessageViewHolder viewHolder, final Message model, int position) {

            if (model.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase(Common.currentUser.getMatric())) {

                if (model.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){
                    viewHolder.yourMessage.setText(model.getMessage());
                    viewHolder.yourMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.theAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

            } else if (model.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase(user_id)){

                if (model.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){

                    viewHolder.messageText.setText(model.getMessage());
                    viewHolder.messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.theAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                }

            }


        }
    };

    messagesRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    messagesRecycler.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    adapter.cleanup();


}

private void sendTheMessage() {

    String message = chatBox.getText().toString();

    if (message.isEmpty()){
    } else {
        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

        messageRef = db.getReference("ChatMessages").child(Common.currentUser.getMatric()).child(user_id).push();
        final String chatMessageId = messageRef.getKey();


        final Message newMessage = new Message(message, "text", date, false, Common.currentUser.getMatric());
        messageRef2 = db.getReference("ChatMessages").child(Common.currentUser.getMatric()).child(user_id);
        messageRef2.child(chatMessageId).setValue(newMessage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                messageRef3 = db.getReference("ChatMessages").child(user_id).child(Common.currentUser.getMatric());
                messageRef3.child(chatMessageId).setValue(newMessage);

                sendNotification();
                chatBox.setText("");

            }
        });


    }

}
```

public class Message {

```
private String message, type;
private long time;
private boolean seen;
private String from;

public Message() {
}

public Message(String message, String type, long time, boolean seen, String from) {
    this.message = message;
    this.type = type;
    this.time = time;
    this.seen = seen;
    this.from = from;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean isSeen() {
    return seen;
}

public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
    this.seen = seen;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}
```

}[This is the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF2CG.png)

Comment: What are the messageRef, messageRef2 and messageRef3 variables? Also, how come you're calling the adapter.cleanup() method? You seem to be setting the same message to two of those ref variables?

Comment: They messageRef, messageRef2 and messageRef3 are Firebase Database References pointing to the message nodes. I am setting same thing to two refs because the message has to appear in the sender's node and the receiver's node which are represented by the Refs..    I have removed the adapter.cleanup() method 'cos it caused a fatal crash.

Comment: I think a description of your message structure and database layout would help with answering this. :)

Comment: I have added the information you require.. please help me

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how your database is structured. Could you explain it? Why is there two representations of the same message, would not a single message with sender and recipient field be easier to work with?

I'm not sure I'll be able to help you, but I'm trying to enable others to do so. Adding the code where you call your methods would probably also be helpful. :)